# NPCs Can't Come to My House (e.g. Invited Guests, Newspaper, Mail, Police...)

Tags: the-sims

I've played the game many times but I've never came across this specific bug...

What happens is, after you call someone (e.g. a person from another family, police), they disappear from the phone since you requested them. Problem is they don't show up, and they remain vanished from the phone as well. When I started noticing this, I noticed that newspaper & mail were as well not arriving for a few days already.

Unfortunately the save of the bugged family was already after the bug has started. It's only one bugged family though, the others seemed normal (via a quick test) although I did not save on them for a decent while.

Running no expansions.

Comment: I seem to vaguely recall that something like this can be caused the edge of the lot having a different elevation than the adjacent sidewalk. I'm not sure of the details, though...

Comment: Well, 1st off I'm sure that the house lot did not incur any elevation changes, 2nd off things were fine for a decent amount of time, perhaps 1, 2 or 3 in-game weeks? I could check the elevations though, perhaps they ARE different than the sidewalk by default for that specific house lot, and perhaps the bug doesn't insta-trigger in the first place.

Now that you mention it, I recall that I've recently expanded my house (unsure if it chronologically overlapped with the bug), although it was to the direction AWAY from the only sidewalk in that house lot (BUT, very close to the water edge).